# Get "OCR A Std" OCR Hook character in JasperReport when exporting to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, report, ocr

I've created a Jasper report which uses OCR strings. The font used is "OCR A Std" wich comes preinstalled with Windows 7. I've packed it in a font-extension jar together with other fonts I'm using. Exporting to PDF works fine, no problem there, the only thing is, it seems I cannot use some extra OCR characters.

Specifically, I need the OCR Hook, OCR Chair and OCR Fork characters. In the [font specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-A_font) the characters have unicode codes U+2440, U+2441 and U+2442. The same information I get in Microsoft Word, when trying to insert special symbol.

If I try to use those characters to output them, I get an empty string.

```
    <parameter name="ocr-codes" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
      <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["\u2440\u2441\u2442"]]></defaultValueExpression> 
    </parameter>
```

After some experimenting I got to OCR Chair and OCR Fork characters with `(char)240` and `(char)254` but cannot find OCR Hook character.

The encoding I'm using throughout the project is UTF-8.

Any ideas why the characters are not accessible via unicode or which is the correct code for the third character?

Comment: Well, in the meantime I've found a TTF with the characters positioned according to the specs.